# JMeter: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException

Tags: jmeter

Im getting the below error message in JMeter groovy.

Response code: 500
Response message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script42.groovy: 3: String too long. The given string is 69427 Unicode code units long, but only a maximum of 65535 is allowed.
@ line 3, column 23.

String is long but cant be reduced since its the payload.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help you without seeing your code, the error is self-explanatory: the String is too big and you cannot operate the strings of that size in Groovy

The options are in:

1. Split it into several parts and then concatenate using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html)
2. Write the payload into a file (again you might need to do this in parts or using streams) and then read the file using [__FileToString() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString)
3. Avoid the interim string and set the payload value using [`sampler` shorthand](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) from the JSR223 PreProcessor